# Ember js firebase upload error al subir archivo

Tags: firebase, ember.js

Hola tengo un problema al momento de querer archivos a firebase me lanza el siguiente error, no entiendo porque me dice que agregue en mirage/config yo no uso eso.

> assert.js:36 Mirage: Your Ember app tried to POST 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ember-firebase-****.appspot.com/o?name=images%2Fbacul-anuncio.png',
>            but there was no route defined to handle this request.
>            Define a route that matches this path in your
>            mirage/config.js file. Did you forget to add your namespace?

este es mi componente donde tengo la logica de subir los datos a firebase

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    /*
        Esto es para subir imagenes declaramos algunas variables

    */
    firebaseApp: Ember.inject.service(),
    storageRef:'',
    file: '',

    /* Fin */
    btn_label:'Guardar',
    actions:{
        click_btn_save(param){

            // create metadata
              var metadata={
                contentType: 'image/png'  
              };
              var storageRef=this.get('firebaseApp').storage().ref();
              var path='images/' + this.get('file').name;
              var uploadTask = storageRef.child(path).put(this.get('file'), metadata);
              //var uploadTask=storageRef.child(path).put(this.get('file'), metadata);

              uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot){
                 var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
                 console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
                 console.log(snapshot.state);
                 }, function(error) {
                     console.log("Ocurrio un errore ");
                     console.log(error);
                 }, function() {
                     console.log("entro a buen recaudo");
                 var downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
                 //newPlan.set('imageUrl', downloadURL);
                 //newPlan.save().then(() => ctrl.transitionToRoute('plans'));
                /* ctrl.set('file', '');
                 ctrl.set('selectedCategory', '');
                 ctrl.set(document.getElementById('output').src, '');
                 ctrl.set('days', '');
                 ctrl.set('isDisabled', true);
                 */
              });


            this.sendAction('action',param)
        },

        didSelectImage(files){
          let reader=new FileReader();  
          reader.onloadend= Ember.run.bind(this,function(){
              console.log("Entro todo bien funciona");
              var dataUrl=reader.result;
              var output= document.getElementById('output');
              output.src=dataUrl;
              this.set('file', files[0]);




          });

          reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
        }
    }
});
```

este es mi template

```
 <!-- app/templates/components/library-item-form.hbs -->
<div class="form-horizontal">

    <div class="form-group">

        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
          {{input type="text" value=item.name class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre de autor"}}
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">

        </div>
    </div>

 <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Image<br>(200x200)</label>
     <div class="col-sm-10"> 
         <img id="output" height="200" width="200">
     <p></p>
     {{x-file-input  alt="hello world" accept="image/png,image/jpg" action=(action "didSelectImage")}}
     </div> 
 </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" {{action 'click_btn_save' item}} disabled="{{if item.isNotValid 'disabled'}}">{{btn_label}}</button>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Alguna ayuda o sugerencia? no se cual es el problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que *Ember Mirage*, qué es un servicio de [objetos simulados](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objeto_simulado) (*mocking service*), redirige la petición, de tal manera que dicha petición no sigue adelante porque Mirage trata de resolverla.

Mirage sirve solamente para pruebas. O implementas el objeto simulado en mirage, o simplemente le pides a mirage que re-envíe la petición a Firebas... Encontrarás más información en http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.2.x/quickstart/#passthrough

Lo que debes hacer es añadir `this.passthrough();` a tu archivo `mirage/config.js`.  Con esta configuración, todas las peticiones que no sean manejadas por mirage serán re-enviadas a la dirección original.

Comment: 1) en el archivo mirage/config.js coloque lo siguiente

this.passthrough('https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/***', ['post']);
La url y seguido de *** y el metodo en este caso post.

2) La segunda manera era deshabilitando el mirage

Para ello en mi archivo config/enviroment.js coloque lo siguiente

if (environment === 'development') {

  ENV['ember-cli-mirage'] = {
  enabled: false
};